# What does multipartite entanglement mean?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

From Wikipedia:

> In the case of systems composed of m > 2 subsystems, the classification of quantum-entangled states is richer than in the bipartite case. Indeed, in multipartite entanglement apart from fully separable states and fully entangled states, there also exists the notion of partially separable states.

Does this mean we can entangle more than two qubits?

Comment: [related on cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48538/26286), and [related on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5206/55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to entangle more than two qubits.
Nice example is GHZ state composed of three qubits:

$$
|\psi_\text{GHZ}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle + |111\rangle)
$$

Another example is W state defined for $n$ qubits followingly
$$
|\psi_\text{w}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(|10\dots00\rangle + |01\dots00\rangle + \dots +|00\dots10\rangle+|00\dots01\rangle).
$$